# Reversing a UIView animation and doing the opposite translationX movement

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a `UIImageView` that animates `translationX: -250`.

I am using `autoreverse, .repeat` to repeat the animation.

However What I would like to happen is as follows:

```
translationX: -250
translationX: 0
translationX: 250
```

and repeat - essentially the image moves from `0 > -250 > 0 > +250` constantly

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  private lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "city_image_01"))
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return imageView
  }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(imageView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
      imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
      imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
      imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
    ])


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 20, delay: 0, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat, .curveEaseInOut], animations: {
      self.imageView.transform = .init(translationX: -250, y: 0)
    }, completion: { _ in })
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. It sounds like you want the image view to animate from -250 to 250. Why do you also want 0 in the mix? Do you want it to do ease-in/ease-out from 0 to -250, then from -250 to 0, then 0 to 250, an finally 250 back to 0?

Comment: Yes that is exactly correct, imagine a pendulum effect, starts in the middle, goes all the way to one side, all the way to the other side and then back to the middle.

Comment: I was reseting the image back to 0 as I thought that would help give me a constant distance to work with, 250 or -250 as it always starts from the middle. It's not required though if it can work without that

Comment: Describe the whole sequence you want in a cycle of the animation, including acceleration. It sounds like You want it to: start from 0, accelerate towards 250 and decelerate to a stop when it gets there. (ease-in-ease-out from 0 to 250). Then it sounds like you want it to begin a cycle of ease-in-ease-out movements from 250 to -250 and back again?

Comment: What does your current code do wrong? (I'm guessing it animates from 0 to -250 and then back to 0.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your animation block slightly you should get the effect you are after:

```
// For the first animation, animate from 0 to -250 (no repeat)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 20, delay: 0, options: [ .curveEaseInOut], animations: {
    self.imageView.transform = .init(translationX: -250, y: 0)

}, completion: { _ in 
    // Once that's done, begin a repeating animation between -250 and 250
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 20, delay: 0, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat, .curveEaseInOut], animations: {
        self.imageView.transform = .init(translationX: 250, y: 0)

    }, completion: nil)
})
```

Comment: Could you explain what `translationX *= -1` is please?

Comment: Sorry, that was leftover from a previous version of the code where I created a variable to track the translation between -250 and 250. I then realized that all I needed to do was to create a second animation from -250 to 250 with the autoreverse option.  (I edited my answer to delete it.)

Answer (score 2):

This should help you achieve the animation you are trying to get

```
        imageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.x")
        animation.duration = 5
        animation.fromValue = 250
        animation.byValue = -500
        animation.autoreverses = true
        animation.repeatCount = .infinity
        self.imageView.layer.add(animation, forKey: "oscilatingAnimation")
```

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: I like this, very lightweight and straight forward solution.

Comment: when you write `UIView.animate(` animation is taken care by CPU where as Core animation APIs like `CABasicAnimation` are taken care of by GPU. So using core animation API is preferred over `UIView.animate`. Quoting Apple docs " This automatic graphics acceleration results in high frame rates and smooth animations without burdening the CPU and slowing down your app."

Comment: @SandeepBhandari you wrote "UIView.animate() animation is taken care by CPU..." That is wrong. UIView animation is a convenience that generates Core Animation under the covers.  You are correct that not using hardware-accelerated animation gives less smooth results and uses more CPU. However your premise that UIView animation does not use hardware acceleration is completely wrong.

Comment: Your animation is pretty close to what I think the OP is asking for, but it will cause the image view to jump from position 0 to position 250 at the start of the animation and then begin animating between 250 and -250. I think the OP wants it to first animate from 0 to 250, and then begin animating back and forth between 250 and -250.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a basic state machine which triggers the next animation stage.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  enum AnimationState {
    case stopped
    case started
    case finishing
  }

  var state: AnimationState = .stopped {
    didSet {
      switch state {
      case .stopped: runAnimation(.init(translationX: -250, y: 0), next: .started)
      case .started: runAnimation(.identity, next: .finishing)
      case .finishing: runAnimation(.init(translationX: 250, y: 0), next: .stopped)
      }
    }
  }

  private lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "city_image_01"))
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return imageView
  }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(imageView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
      imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
      imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
      imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
    ])

    state = .stopped
  }


  func runAnimation(_ transform: CGAffineTransform, next state: AnimationState) {
    UIView.animate(
      withDuration: 20,
      delay: 0,
      options: [.curveEaseInOut],
      animations: { self.imageView.transform = transform },
      completion: { _ in self.state = state }
    )
  }

}
```